# HttpWebRequest versus HttpClient: Handling of HTTP 100: Continue causes exception in HttpClient but not in HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I'm working on cleaning up and updating some legacy code that posts about 1kB of data to a server, every minute or so. The server is outside of my control, but always responds with [HTTP 100 continue](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.1.1) before sending `HTTP 200 OK`.

The old code (see below) works, but uses [HttpWebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=netframework-4.8) which is not recommended for new development, so I would like to update the code if possible. The code runs in a backgroundthread, so there is no need for asynchronous calls.

I wrote a new implementation of the legacy code with HttpClient, but it throws exceptions. My guess is that the exception is caused by the `HTTP 100 continue` response of the server, as posting the data to another test-server that doesn't use this response works fine.

**Legacy code:**

```cs
    private void Legacy()
        {
            string s = "POSTDATA";
            string output = "";
            try
            {
                Encoding encoding1 = (Encoding)new ASCIIEncoding();
                HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://myurl.com");
                httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
                httpWebRequest.Timeout = 10000;
                httpWebRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                byte[] bytes = encoding1.GetBytes(s);
                httpWebRequest.Headers.Clear();
                httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
                httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;
                httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "it");
                httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                httpWebRequest.ContentLength = (long)s.Length;
                Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
                requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                Stream responseStream = httpWebRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
                Encoding encoding2 = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, encoding2);
                char[] buffer = new char[512];
                streamReader.Read(buffer, 0, 512);
                requestStream.Close();
                requestStream.Dispose();
                streamReader.Close();
                streamReader.Dispose();
                responseStream.Close();
                responseStream.Dispose();
                for (int index2 = 0; index2 < buffer.Length; ++index2)
                    output += buffer[index2].ToString();
                MessageBox.Show(output);
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

**New code:**

```cs
    private static readonly HttpClient _httpclient = new HttpClient();
        private void NewCode()
        {
            _httpclient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
            _httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            _httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
            _httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "it");

            var t = Task.Run(TEST);
            t.Wait();
            string tmp = t.Result;
            MessageBox.Show(tmp);
        }

        private static async Task<String> TEST()
        {
            try
            {
                string s = "POSTDATA";
                StringContent cont = new StringContent(s, Encoding.ASCII, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                HttpResponseMessage Req = await _httpclient.PostAsync("http://myurl.com", cont);
                Req.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string Response = await Req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return Response;
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);
                return "";
            }
        }
```

Exception thrown: `Error while copying content to a stream.`
Innerexception: `Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed.`
Stacktrace:

```
at System.Net.ConnectStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.WebExceptionWrapperStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult
asyncResult) 
at
System.Net.Http.StreamToStreamCopy.BufferReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
```

I checked the requests and responses of both implementations with Wireshark and they are exactly the same, so I guess the implementation with HttpClient is wrong somewhere. So my questions are:

- Is there a problem in my implementation with HttpClient, or is this a
  fundamental problem?
- Is there another way of doing this without
  using the legacy stuff?
- Should I even bother updating the legacy
  code?

I'd very much like to hear your thoughts on this.

Comment: That setting belongs to the current ServicePoint. You can set  `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;` before new connections are created. This property defaults to `true` and applies to `POST` requests. HttpClient can also use the `HttpRequestHeaders` to set the related `Expect` value (`ExpectContinue`). HttpWebRequest can use it's `ServicePoint` property to set the value to the currently assigned ServicePoint.

Comment: Those were just some informations about the `Expect100Cotinue` setting, for you to take a look at what it does, Usually, when a client doesn't react to the `Continue` request, the connection hangs and finally times out. So you don't read *The connection was closed*, but *The connection timed out*. What is the `StatusCode`? Have you tested the WebRequest code in the same exact environment (Windows version and FW version). Have you verified what is the `SecurityProtocol` that was negotiated? Did the server request a validation of its certificate(s)? etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried changing `Expect100Continue` to both true and false in both the legacy code as well as in the new code. I see the difference in Wireshark, but unfortunately, it doesn't change anything in the behaviour of the code. The HttpClient throws the same exception, the HttpWebRequest does not, while they are tested in the exact same environment (same program even). The server also doesn't change its behaviour and keeps sending `100 Continue` messages before `200 OK`.I'm not sure how to check `StatusCode` or `SecurityProtocol` as the exception is thrown at `PostAsync`.

Comment: Those details are quite important, if one cannot test the connection. One thing you should try is to eliminate that pseudo-threading stuff (that's not the way to use a HttpClient in *asynchronous mode*).

Comment: I don't think there is a `SecurityProtocol`, as the server is not using https but just http. I don't need any of the asynchronous code, as it is run in a backgroundthread anyway (just like the `HttpWebRequest` is blocking). The `-Async` code and `Tasks` are new for me, if there is a better way of using the `HttpClient` synchronously I would be happy to change it, but I couldn't find any examples using it that way.

Comment: If it's HTTP, then no SSL handshake, so no SecurityProtocol or validation callback. The code you have there is snippet-standard extra-minimal boilerplate. The WebRequest code is more or less the same thing. -- The timeout is too short (`TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);`), it's 1/6 of the standard, so also remove that line. HttpCient should be used as a `static` object and it uses the `async/await` pattern. You can use instance objects, though. It's not a problem while testing. It becomes a problem if you have multiple requests created one after the other.

Comment: I have removed the timeout, but it makes no difference. I used an instance as HttpClient and used `-Async(...).Result` to make blocking operations. Still, no difference in exceptions...

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround:**

To me, it seemed that something is going wrong internally inside the framework, or that some setting somewhere is wrong. So, I tried several different methods to do the same HTTP POST request, which I also verified again with Wireshark.

Below is new code, not showing any exception, but nevertheless using the HttpClient instead of the HttpWebRequest.

It appears that I get the same exception as before again if I use `ReadAsStringAsync()` instead of `Req.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();`. It also appears that it matters which value I use for [HttpCompletionOption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcompletionoption?view=netframework-4.8), because if I change it from `ResponseHeadersRead` to `ResponseContentRead` I also get the same  exception again.

However, I don't understand why these things matter. So if anyone knows why this could be the case, or if there is another solution, I would be more than happy to hear it.

```cs
    private static readonly HttpClient _httpclient = new HttpClient();
        private void NewCode()
        {
            _httpclient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
            _httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            _httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
            _httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "it");

            var t = Task.Run(TEST3);
            t.Wait();
            string tmp = t.Result;
            MessageBox.Show(tmp);
        }

        private static async Task<String> TEST3()
        {
            try
            {
                HttpRequestMessage x = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://myurl.com");
                Dictionary<string, string> postParams = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                postParams.Add("Param", "Value");
                x.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postParams);
                HttpResponseMessage Req = await _httpclient.SendAsync(x, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
                Req.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                Stream str = await Req.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                Encoding encoding2 = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(str, encoding2);
                return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                return Ex.Message;
            }
        }
```